# grid_columnconfigure() Not Working Inside my Frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, interface

Here is My Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myframe = Frame(root, bg="red")
myframe.pack()

btn1 = Button(myframe, text="Button 1", font="Comicsans 15 bold")
btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn2 = Button(myframe, text="Button 2", font="Comicsans 15 bold")
btn2.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

How do I make `grid_columnconfigure()` work ?

Comment: Change `root.grid_columnconfigure` to `myframe.grid_columnconfigure`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it on `root`, but the widget inside `root` is using `pack`. If you expect it to affect the buttons, you need to call it on `myframe`:

```
myframe.grid_columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
```